# How to plot circles in real time using RANDOM values from a CSV file that is being continuously updated?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot random points in a circular fashion in real-time which refreshes once per second. I have made one program that puts random values in a CSV file and another program that plots a circle with those values. When I run it, it does not show any error but I am unable to see any output. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Program that updates the CSV file**

```
import csv
import random
import time


x_value = 0
total_1 = 1000
total_2 = 1000


fieldnames = ["x_value", "total_1", "total_2"]

with open('daata.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()


while True:

    with open('data.csv','a') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    info = {
        "x_value": x_value,
        "total_1": total_1,
        "total_2": total_2
    }

    csv_writer.writerow(info)
    print(x_value, total_1, total_2)

    x_value += 1
    total_1 = total_1 + random.randint(-6,8)
    total_2 = total_2 + random.randint(-5,6)
time.sleep(1)
```

**Main Program**

```
import random
from itertools import count
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()

def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    x = data['x_value']
    y1 = data['total_1']
    y2 = data['total_2']

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x, y1, label='Channel 1')
    plt.plot(x, y2, label='Channel 2')

    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval = 1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert with animated plot but this should work for your **Main Program**:

```
import random
from itertools import count
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

pathfile = "data_anim.csv"

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lines = [
    ax.plot([], [], marker="o", label='Channel 1')[0], # carefull here to get obj[0] because matplotlib.lines.Line2D is a list
    ax.plot([], [], marker="o", label='Channel 2')[0]
]
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()

def read_data():
    " Function to read your dataframe and return values """
    data = pd.read_csv(pathfile)
    x = data['x_value']
    y1 = data['total_1']
    y2 = data['total_2']
    return x, y1, y2

def init():
    """ Init your lines """
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        line.set_data([],[])
    return lines

def animate(i):
    """ Function to update data for your lines """
    x, y1, y2 = read_data()
    lines[0].set_data(x[:i], y1[:i])
    lines[1].set_data(x[:i], y2[:i])
    ax.relim() # reset intern limits of the current axes
    ax.autoscale_view()   
    return lines


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ani = FuncAnimation(
        fig, 
        animate, 
        init_func=init, 
        interval = 1000,
        blit=False # need to be on false to redraw and adapt axis each time
    )
    plt.show()
```

Here are the result I got on my computer:

[image]

Comment: Bro I needed random circular plots not straight line plots

Comment: What do you mean by circular plot ? Polar plot or just circular maker ?

Comment: Anyone of them would work, I just need them in a circular fashion

Comment: Points in the circumference of a circle would be preferable though.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If by circular plot you mean polar plot then you have to change coordinates (polar plot https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html).

If by circular plot you mean round marker then just change the marker of the line by using `ax.plot([], [], marker="o", label='Channel 1')`

Comment: I want a circular marker, where should I write the line of code you sent?

Comment: Common that's 10th line of code, try to understand a bit what I wrote. I edited my post.

Comment: I am still getting a straight line bro, instead of making two graphs can you use the three values to generate circular markers, with x being incremented by 1 bring the x coordinate of the circle and y1 and y2 as y coordinate and radius. I'll sure mark the answer as correct when I am able to get the circles man

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an image of what you want or something similar of what you want ?

Comment: I just talked to the people who wrote the question, they meant to set the size of plot to 100 x 8 and generate a continuous random graph which repeats after 99 rows and this is what they were calling circular fashion. Sorry man

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202357/discussion-between-yohann-l-and-vihaan-misra).